# Javascript else on a new line

Tags: javascript, formatting

When creating an if block, I was wondering if there was any reason beyond personal preference to use the standard bracket formatting vs the second one I listed.

I've run code in the second format without any obvious issues (no ASI or unexpected errors), just looking for some clarification or insight on if there could be any possible issues in the future if I permanently switch to this style.

```
// Standard formatting
if (true) {

} else {

}

// Other formatting
if (true) {

}
else {

}
```

Comment: "beyond personal preference"... no, they behave identically.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130134/jslint-else-and-expected-exactly-one-space-between-and-else-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces and tabs are not considered to be significant in Javascript in most cases. (I believe all, but I can't find a source for that)

You can technically put all of your code on one line (as most minification algorithms do), but that won't be very readable. In your own code, it comes down to solely personal preference, it will not cause any errors or cause the code to run slower if there are spaces (though more spaces will take longer to load if the JS is not minified).

Best practice is to keep your code style consistent throughout your projects.

Answer (score 1):

None, they are equivalent if you wanted you could put the code in one line as well and it would work. Usually people have personal preferences, as well as some companies require you to write the code in a specific way in order to standardize it and make it so anyone taking over your project knows what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the brackets, it wil just work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4ywahnof/1/

```
(function () {

    var t = 1;
    if (t == 1) alert("hi");

    else alert("no hi");

})();
```